# Maven: dependency appears in effective pom but not in dependency tree

Tags: maven, maven-3, dependency-management

Working on a multi-module project.

```
GrandParent
        \
         Parent
             \
             Child
```

`GrandParent` has `rogue_1` module in its `<dependencyManagement>` section as **provided** !

`Parent` does **NOT** have `rogue_1` in its `pom.xml` at all.

`Child` does **NOT** have `rogue_1` as a direct dependency in its `pom.xml`.

However it includes several other projects some of which *may* include `rogue_1`. (at least one **does** depend on `rogue_1`)

To be on the safe side, on **ALL** `Child`'s dependencies I have added exclusions as follows:

```
<dependency> <!-- a direct dependency of Child -->
    <groupId>erso</groupId>
    <artifactId>galen</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>resistance</groupId>
            <artifactId>rogue_1</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

(in case for example `galen.erso` is bringing in the `resistance.rogue_1`)

**However**: `rogue_1` **DOES** end up being displayed as a dependency in the outcome of

**`mvn help:effective-pom`**

(as **provided** !)

It is **NOT** in the ouctome of

`mvn dependency:tree`

Any suggestions?

Comment: could you clarify if it's showing up in `<dependencyManagement> <dependencies>` or 
 `<dependencies>`. I think it is ok to show up in former but not the later. Is this the case. Could you confirm. ++1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`mvn help:effective-pom`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/effective-pom-mojo.html)

is basically a merger between the super POM (grand /+parent) dependencies and the simple POM that you defined at the project level. Hence you do see the `rogue_1` under the XML created by effective-pom, of course your grandparent pom's `dependencyManagement` being the source. Here is a [detailed read](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-pom.html) over the same.

[`mvn dependency:tree`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html)

on the other hand displays the tre of the dependencies used in your project. As you mentioned you've excluded this out of all your mentioned dependencies, so you shouldn't find the artifact listed here.

By the way, in both the cases the chances of having the `rogue_1` in the classpath of your `child` module is zero.

Comment: could you clarify if rouge_1 will show up in `<dependencyManagement> <dependencies>` or 
 `<dependencies>`. I think it is ok to show up in former but not the later. Is this the case. Could you confirm. ++1

Answer (score 0):

You may get this sort of behaviour, if you have a profile either in your project, or one that you're inheriting (and that is somehow getting activated). As far as I recall, dependencies defined in a `<profile/>` do not show up on the dependency tree.